# Phusion Passenger Rbenv Capistrano

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, passenger, rbenv, phusion

I can't seem to figure out why passenger is not loading the web app. I have nginx running following this tutorial: https://gorails.com/deploy/ubuntu/16.04.
Using rbenv and seems like Passenger isn't serving any applications for some reason.

```
00:32 passenger:restart 01 passenger-config restart-app 
/home/deploy/aldrinclement/current --ignore-app-not-running 01 There 
are no Phusion Passenger-served applications running whose paths begin 
with '/home/deploy/aldrinclement/current'
```

Comment: I'm having the same issue. Any chance you figured out why it wasn't working? I'm following the same tutorial.

Comment: Have you figured this out by now? If not, try updating the question with your nginx configuration (/etc/nginx/sites-available/default usually)

Comment: I have exactly the same issue. I have also fllowed Phusion Passenger instructions that would seem trusthworthy but they do not work. https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/walkthroughs/deploy/ruby/ownserver/nginx/oss/xenial/install_passenger.html